# Initialise lazy variable in SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a delegate in a view that depends on data inputted when initialising the view. The `fileFormat` should be passed into this delegate.

I tried using a lazy variable (to prevent uninitialised self errors), but as lazy variables mutate whenever first called, that wouldn't work:

```swift
struct EditorView: View {

    let fileFormat: UTIType
    @Binding var text: String

    lazy var highlightDelegate = HighlightDelegate(format: fileFormat)

    // something that uses `highlightDelegate`:
    // Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
}
```

If I use a computed property, `highlightDelegate` would be initialised every time it gets called which isn't quite what I need - each view should initialise one of these structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialise `highlightDelegate` in the init of your view, no need to make it lazy.

```
struct EditorView: View {

    let fileFormat: UTIType
    @Binding var text: String

    let highlightDelegate: HighlightDelegate

    init(fileFormat: UTIType, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.fileFormat = fileFormat
        self._text = text
        self.highlightDelegate = HighlightDelegate(format: fileFormat)
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the `_text` for in the initialiser?

Comment: @Smally that's how you access (and assign to) the `Binding` rather than assigning to the `String`. This is how you initialise `State`/`Binding` properties when they're injected.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Ty! you learn something new every day